Confidence level on excluded lifetime of decay
Could someone help me understand the ideas behind setting confidence levels on decay lifetimes. Like what Super K has been doing on the proton.
Given the count rate of the decays is a poisson distribution, which has a standard deviation of the square root of the mean, are we somehow working out how large the mean would have to be to be far enough away that within a certain confidence level we would see no counts?

A sketch of the process might be as follows:
If you have some decay process with a an exponential decay timescale of $\tau$ and you set up an experiment that lasts $t$ seconds (where $t \ll \tau$), then the the number of decays you might expect to see is
$$N_d \simeq \left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)N_0\ , $$
where $N_0$ in this case would be the number of protons being monitored.
The statistics of the Possion distibution then tells you that the probability of detecting $n$ decays (assuming your experiment is perfect etc.) is given by
$$P(n) = \frac{N_d^n}{n!}\exp(-N_d)$$
and if $n=0$, then $P(0) = \exp(-N_d)$.
Suppose then we want a 90% lower limit to what $\tau$ could be. We can say
$$ 0.1 > \exp(-N_0\ t/\tau) $$
Taking natural log of both sides
$$2.30 > N_0\ t/\tau$$
$$ \tau > 0.434\ N_0\ t\ . $$
Matsumoto et al. (2022) give results from "0.37 megaton years" of Kamiokande monitoring from proton decay. This is a water-based experiment, so I think this figure corresponds to $N_0 t = 3.9\times 10^{42}$ s.
Using the naive calculation above, the limit on $\tau$ would be $> 1.7 \times 10^{42}$ s.
The actual 90% limit quoted is $\sim 10^{41}$ s. The problem with the naive analysis is that it assumes there is nothing else going on in the experiment - particularly no "background events" unassociated with proton decay. In Kamiokande there is a (very low) background rate of a few detected counts due to neutrino interactions. So you are actually always detecting some decays, the question is whether there is an excess over those you expect due to a small number of background events. This reduces your experiment sensitivity and consequently the limits on the proton-decay lifetime. Secondly, the analysis above assumes all the proton decays could be detected, whereas in fact the estimate is that only 17% would be - which also reduces the naive lifetime limit by a factor of 5.

Suppose, the count rate of the decay process is a random variable $Y$, which is distributed as  $Pois(\lambda)$. Because $\lambda$ is the decay rate, we know that on average we get $\mu_{counts} = \lambda \cdot \Delta t$ decays in an time interval $\Delta t$. However, as the process is random, we also expect that the count will not be exactly $\mu_{counts}$, but that it somewhat "scatters" around this value. Therefore, it makes sense to ask the following question: "Which is the minimal count and what is the maximal count which we expect to obtain in 95% of the cases?"
This question is answered by calculating the 95% confidence interval of the counts using $\lambda \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\lambda}$ -- where I assumed $\Delta t = 1$. For example, if we assume $\lambda=6$ this is what we get:

If we perform an experiment the true rate $\lambda$ is unknown. Thus, we have to estimate the true value $\lambda$ from the dataset. This is the setting which we usually encounter, but the interpretation of the confidence interval is becomes "complicates". To read about the correct interpretation I recommend you google "confidence interval vs. credible interval". Here, I will only say that

The 95% confidence interval is not the probability that the true value of $\lambda$ lies within the interval.
The confidence interval is a statement about our expectation if we repeat the experiment: If we repeat the same experiment $n$ times, and each time we construct a 95% confidence interval, then we expect (in the long run) that 95% of our confidence intervals contain the population value.
The last point can be generalised: We don't have to repeat the same experiment, but we consider $n$ completely different confidence intervals -- e.g. the first is about the occurrence rate of the letter $n$ in english literature, the second is about the average income per house hold in the united state etc. If each study presents a 95 confidence interval (and if we assume that there exists no p-value hacking and no publication bias), then 95% of these confidence intervals should contain their true population value.

